# Can I notify when any bluetooth of paired device is enabled?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi I am working with embedded bluetooth device connection with my android application.

My application is installed in Android phone and phone has some paired bluetooth devices, Now I want that if any paired bluetooth device is enabled(starts/turns on) the application should receive notification.

of-course bluetooth will be enabled in phone and bluetooth devices will be within range.

please let me know How this is possible ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing automatic that can detect this, you will have to make both your App and the paired device do some work to detect this. TYhere could be 2 options :

1. Your app could do some periodic device discovery (low frequency - else it will kill the battery) to search for the paired devices in vicinity.
   The paired devices on getting enabled / starting on should put itself to be discoverable.
2. A better way is for the apired device to autimaically initiate a connection once it comes on to the device it was paired with, and typically on most phones by default if Bluetooth is turned on its also scanning for incoming connection , so your app can be ready to accept incoming connections.

Answer (score 1):

How about using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED

To check all changed states and then comparing what the new state is:

```
 STATE_DISCONNECTED, STATE_CONNECTING, STATE_CONNECTED etc.
```